# Netbeans: Only show ToDo list of active project

Tags: netbeans

Is there a way to only display the ToDo list of the current active project in Netbeans instead off all the projects in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the window where you see todo, look on the left side a row of icons, by pressing on them you select whether shows for the active file, project or all projects.
Also there is a filter so you can adjust what exactly you want it to display.